# Parse Whois data using Regex - Ignore field Repetition

Tags: python, regex, parsing, whois

I'm trying to parse the result of a whois query. I'm interested in retrieving the route, descr and origin fields as shown below:

```
route:          129.45.67.8/91
descr:          FOO-BAR
descr:          Information 2
origin:         AS5462
notify:         foo@bar.net
mnt-by:         AS5462-MNT
remarks:        For abuse notifications please file an online case @ http://www.foo.com/bar
changed:        foo@bar.net 20000101
source:         RIPE
remarks:        ****************************
remarks:        * THIS OBJECT IS MODIFIED
remarks:        * Please note that all data that is generally regarded as personal
remarks:        * data has been removed from this object.
remarks:        * To view the original object, please query the RIPE Database at:
remarks:        * http://www.foo.net/bar
remarks:        ****************************

route:          123.45.67.8/91
descr:          FOO-BAR
origin:         AS3269
mnt-by:         BAR-BAZ
changed:        foo@bar.net 20000101
source:         RIPE
remarks:        ****************************
remarks:        * THIS OBJECT IS MODIFIED
remarks:        * Please note that all data that is generally regarded as personal
remarks:        * data has been removed from this object.
remarks:        * To view the original object, please query the RIPE Database at:
remarks:        * http://www.ripe.net/whois
remarks:        ****************************
```

To do so I use the following code and regex:

```
search = "FOO-BAR"

with open(FILE, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    r = re.compile(r'route:\s+(.*)\ndescr:\s+(.*' + search + '.*).*\norigin:\s+(.*)', re.IGNORECASE)
    res = r.findall(content)
    print res
```

It does work as expected with result containing only one descr field, however it ignores results containing multiple descr field.

I get the following result in this case:

```
[('123.45.67.8/91', 'FOO-BAR', 'AS3269')]
```

The expected result is to have the route field, first descr field in case of multiple descr line and origin field.

```
[('129.45.67.8/91', 'FOO-BAR', 'AS5462'), ('123.45.67.8/91', 'FOO-BAR', 'AS3269')]
```

What would be the correct regex to parse the results containing one AND several descr line?

Comment: What's wrong with https://code.google.com/p/pywhois/ ?

Comment: regex seems a bit overkill for this task. What about linestartwith() and some counters ?

Comment: @IntrepidBrit My understanding is pywhois produces parsed WHOIS data from a given domain name, where in this particular case WHOIS data are produced from a free text search.

Comment: @georgesl I might look at linestartwith(), I didn't know about it however I'd like to have a solution using regex as well.

Comment: I completely rewrite the question, hopefully it will be on-topic now, thanks

Comment: Split string by route or \n\n and then use your regex for each substring.

Comment: @Moustache - that's okay. Just wanted to double check you weren't needlessly re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: @Moustache - You're correct in your pywhois understanding, but I was just making you aware of it's existence. You might have been able to modify your program "upstream" :)

Answer (score 2):

I've come quite close from what you ask :

```
import re

search = "FOO-BAR"

with open('whois', "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    r = re.compile(     r''                 # 
            'route:\s+(.*)\n'               # 
            '(descr:\s+(?!FOO-BAR).*\n)*'   # Capture 0-n lines with descr: field but without FOO-BAR 
            'descr:\s+(FOO-BAR)\n'          # Capture at least one line with descr: and FOO-BAR
            '(descr:\s+(?!FOO-BAR).*\n)*'   # Capture 0-n lines with descr: field but without FOO-BAR
            'origin:\s+(.*)',               #
            re.IGNORECASE)  
    #r = re.compile('(route:\n)((descr:)(?!FOO-BAR)(.*)\n)*((descr:)(FOO-BAR)\n)?((descr:)(?!FOO-BAR)(.*)\n)*')
    res = r.findall(content)
    print res
```

The result :

```
>>> [('129.45.67.8/91', '', 'FOO-BAR', 'descr:          Information 2\n', 'AS5462'),
     ('123.45.67.8/91', '', 'FOO-BAR', '', 'AS3269')]
```

With a bit of cleaning, you can get your result